# how to check if a TextView exist

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I created on loop 5 TextViews, set to them some text and added they to LinearLayout.
After that I need to change text in them. I want to delete all of them and create new one on loop again. But before TextView deleting I must to be sure that its exists. How to do it?

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
   TextView tv = new TextView(context);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   tv.setLayoutParams(params);
   tv.setId(i);
   tv.setText("some data");
   ll.addView(tv);
}
```

Thank you for help and your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete all of them then just perform `ll.removeAllViews()`.

Comment: Thank you! Good idea, but in this LinearLayout present another Views :) I need them :)

Comment: Then add an additional `LinearLayout` to this layout and add all the `TextView`s to this inner layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a reference to each of the text views you create if you want to remove them.
If I understand your question correctly, simply create an array of TextViews with 5 elements and run the loop to do what you want with them.
To "delete" them you can call:

```
tv[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To change text and re-add them:

```
tv[i].setText("New Text");
tv[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about it and it works. But interesting how I can delete View that I created from code in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to hold references to your `TextViews` in a list, so you can interact with them later on after you've created them. Otherwise you won't be able to see the objects.